# GWT Disable mouse wheel scrolling for Scroll Panel

Tags: gwt, vertical-scrolling

I have two scrollpanel, try to implement them to scroll vertically at the same time, here are the code

```
//leftSide and rightSide class has scrollPanel
final ScrollPanel scrollPanelLeft = leftSide.getScrollPanel();
final ScrollPanel scrollPanelRight = rightSide.getScrollPanel();

leftSide.removeMouseHandlers();
leftSide.removeScrollHandler();

HandlerRegistration mouseWheelScrollHandler =   
scrollPanelLeft.addDomHandler(new MouseWheelHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent event) {

            int currentVertPos =   
scrollPanelLeft.getVerticalScrollPosition();
            if (!lockSide)
                scrollPanelRight.setVerticalScrollPosition(currentVertPos);


        }
    }, MouseWheelEvent.getType());

    leftSide.addScrollHandler(mouseWheelScrollHandler);

 leftSide.addHandler(mouseWheelScrollHandler);
```

When scroll on left side, right side move to the same vertical position, however, then left side move again itself (scroll down), so right side seems to be lag and could not be at the same time.  It seems left side run default scrolling mouse wheel event.  How to disable it or other way to make them scroll vertically at same time? Thanks for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to reproduce your problem. When I had `ScrollHandler` only on the left panel, the right panel was scrolling smoothly. But when I had
`ScrollHandler`s on both left and right panel the scrolling was lagging.

The solution I came with was to scroll the the right panel only when the mouse was over the left panel (and vice versa). With this approach both panels were scrolling smoothly.

Here is a fully working example code:

```
public class ScrollTest {

    private boolean mouseOverLeftPanel = false;
    private boolean mouseOverRightPanel = false;

    public ScrollTest() {
        final ScrollPanel scrollPanelLeft = new ScrollPanel();
        final ScrollPanel scrollPanelRight = new ScrollPanel();

        scrollPanelLeft.setPixelSize(100, 150);
        scrollPanelRight.setPixelSize(100, 150);

        VerticalPanel highContentLeft = new VerticalPanel();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            highContentLeft.add(new Label("Label " + Integer.toString(i)));

        VerticalPanel highContentRight = new VerticalPanel();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            highContentRight.add(new Label("Label " + Integer.toString(i)));

        scrollPanelLeft.add(highContentLeft);
        scrollPanelRight.add(highContentRight);

        // scroll handlers
        scrollPanelLeft.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                if(mouseOverLeftPanel)
                    scrollPanelRight.setVerticalScrollPosition(scrollPanelLeft.getVerticalScrollPosition());
            }
        });

        scrollPanelRight.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                if(mouseOverRightPanel)
                    scrollPanelLeft.setVerticalScrollPosition(scrollPanelRight.getVerticalScrollPosition());
            }
        });

        // mouse over handlers
        scrollPanelLeft.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
                mouseOverLeftPanel = true;
            }
        }, MouseOverEvent.getType());

        scrollPanelRight.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
                mouseOverRightPanel = true;
            }
        }, MouseOverEvent.getType());

        // mouse out handlers
        scrollPanelLeft.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
                mouseOverLeftPanel = false;
            }
        }, MouseOutEvent.getType());

        scrollPanelRight.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
                mouseOverRightPanel = false;
            }
        }, MouseOutEvent.getType());

        HorizontalPanel wrapper = new HorizontalPanel();
        wrapper.add(scrollPanelLeft);
        wrapper.add(scrollPanelRight);

        RootPanel.get().add(wrapper);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it, thanks for your time and the solution!